# move_upload_file() not inserting to right directory

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload

How do I download a pdf file that is in different directory path? Or is it possible to upload just only the file and do not include the directory path?

So this modal is located at the root folder `xampp\htdocs\rootfolder\modal.php`
[image]

and the repository Files is where the files are stored, and code where it does the adding is located at the admin folder.

[image]

This is where my modal located at.

[image]

This is my code to retrieve the file.

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $row['research_file'];?>" class="btn btn-info"> <?php echo $row['research_file'];?> </a>
```

This what happens everytime I click the button `..files/Images/certificate0.pdf`.

[image]

Comment: Your are using absolute or relative path?

Comment: @AloHA_ChiCken relative path.

Comment: try using absolute path. See whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving the correct path of the file

you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` to get the full path of the directory

use `echo '__DIR__'.'/admin/'. $row['research_file'];`

Comment: Hello it does not work for me, I think it's because of because of the `..\files\`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the relative path(at $row['research_file']) you have given.
If your modal file and admin directory is in same directory then your path should be './admin/files/RepositoryFiles/[yourfilename]'.

Comment: My modal is outside the admin, it's like `localhost/projectname/modal.php` and the file stored is at `localhost/projectname/admin/files/repositoryfiles/`

Comment: Then you path should be '../admin/files/repositoryfiles/'.

Comment: I tried `../admin/files/repositoryfiles/` but it gives me `failed to open stream: No such file directory` and `unable to move tmp file to file`

Comment: Sorry!! My apologies.
Try './admin/files/repositoryfiles/'.
Because admin folder and modal.php file is in same directory.
or you can also give path as 'admin/files/repositoryfiles/<yourfilename>'.
Hopefully, this time it will work!!

Comment: I'm sorry but still it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Can you please share your generated url after you click button located in modal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230785/discussion-between-kai-and-darshit-dhameliya).